# A generalization of the "Four vertex theorem"

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Assume that  $S$  is a  compact surface  in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Its  Gaussian curvature is  denoted  by $\kappa$.

Is it true to say that $\kappa$  has  more than two critical points?

Comment: Without boundary, I assume?

Comment: @JohnHughes  Yes  without  boundary. First we can assume  it surrounds  a convex region.

Comment: Lovely question!

Comment: The Four Vertex Theorem, as I know it, is stated in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @JohnHughes  Thank you so much Prof Hughes.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  Yes its original formulation is stated for a (convex) closed curve $\gamma$ in  the plane. Now we try to generalize it for  higher dimensional $\gamma$, that is  surfaces.

Comment: As the $2$-dimensional case isn't trivial to prove (it did indeed take some 50 years), I wish you good luck.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  The original for  convex $\gamma$ takes 50 years!?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to start with (compact) surfaces of revolution, but the computation even in that case isn't easy. I'm pondering it.

Comment: You can prescribe Gaussian curvature function on the smooth sphere as long as it is positive (Kazdan and Warner, I think)  and then embed the surface isometrically in $R^3$ using Pogorelov's theorem. Thus, the answer to your question is negative, you can have exactly two critical points.

Comment: Ah, we were inclined to say that, @MoisheCohen, and I knew Kazdan-Warner, but not Pogorelov. Thanks!! +2.

Comment: I've been playing with explicit surfaces of revolution; coming up with one that does what's needed is surprisingly difficult (for me, anyhow).

Comment: @MoisheCohen  Thank  you very  much for your  answer.

Comment: And it turns out (see my answer) that you don't need any big theorems at all...just 5 weeks of noodling. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prescribe Gaussian curvature function on the smooth sphere as long as it is positive (Kazdan and Warner, 1980s) and then embed the surface isometrically as a convex surface in $E^3$: Alexandrov, Pogorelov, Nierenberg. The history of the embedding result is a bit convoluted: It was first proven by Alexandrov in 1940s without any smoothness properties; smoothness (as well as uniqueness of convex embedding) was established shortly thereafter by Pogorelov and few years later by Nierenberg. Nierenberg's proof is probably the most readable. I will chase the references when I have time.

Thus, the answer to your question is negative, you can have exactly two critical points. It would be interesting though to find out if your question about critical points has a positive answer for the **mean curvature** function.

Comment: Thank you  for your very interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concrete example of a 2-vertex surface.

TL;DR: glue together two half-ellipsoids.

Consider the surface of revolution parameterized by 
$$
S(u, v) = (\varphi(v) \cos u, \varphi(v) \sin u, \psi(v)).
$$
The "profile curve" $(\varphi, \psi)$ completely determines the curvature. Computing the second fundamental form and writing things out yields
\begin{align}
K &= \frac{N}{D}\\
N &= -(\psi'^2)\varphi'' + \varphi' \psi' \psi'' \\
D &= \varphi (\varphi'^2 + \psi'^2)^2
\end{align}
Let's look at one quarter of an ellipse, $E_{a,r}$ parameterized via 
\begin{align}
    \varphi(t)  &= ar \sin t \\
    \psi(t) &= r \cos t,
\end{align}
for $t \in [0, \pi/2]$. 
Direct computation shows that 
\begin{align}
N &= ar^3 \sin^2 t \sin t + ar^3 \cos^2 t \sin t \\
&= ar^3 \sin t ~~(\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t) \\
&= ar^3 \sin t \\
D &= ar \sin t ~~(a^2 r^2 \cos^2 t + r^2 \sin'^2 t)^2 \\
&= ar^5 \sin t ~~(a^2 \cos^2 t + \sin'^2 t)^2 
\end{align}
so that the Gaussian curvature of the associated surface of revolution is 
\begin{align}
K&= \frac{N}{D} \\
&= \frac{1}{r^2 \left(a^2 \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t\right)^2}.
\end{align}

Letting 
\begin{align}
u &= a^2 \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t.
\end{align}
we see (via some calculus that I'm not going to write out here, because I know you can do it) that for $a > 1$, $u$ is a decreasing function on $[0, \pi/2]$, and for $0 < a < 1$, $u$ is increasing on the same interval. This means that the Gaussian curvature, as a function of $v$, is either increasing ($a < 1)$ or decreasing ($a > 1$).

Furthermore, at $t = \pi/2$, the point on our ellipse has horizontal tangent, is at location 
$$
P = (\psi(\pi/2)), \varphi(\pi/2)) = (0, ar)
$$
and the surface there has curvature 
$$
K = \frac{1}{r^2},
$$
while at $t = 0$, the point is at 
$$
Q = (r, 0)
$$ 
with a vertical tangent, 
and the surface there has curvature
$$
K = \frac{1}{r^2 a^4}.
$$

So if we choose $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $r = 2$, we get an half-egg-like surface whose curvature goes from $4$ (at $t = 0$) to $1$ (at $t = \pi/2$).

On the other hand, if we choose $a = 2$ and $r = \frac{1}{2}$, the curvature goes from 
$\frac{1}{4}$ (at $t = 0$) to $1$ (at $t = \pi/2$).

If we flip this second curve across the $y$-axis, or simply parametrize it by 
$$
\pi /2 \le t \le \pi,
$$ 
and join it to the first, we end up with a surface of revolution whose curvature increases steadily along its axis, from $1/4$ to $4$.

It seems only fair to include a picture of this surface, badly created in Matlab:
[image: the "egg"]

and, for the record, the matlab code that created it:

```
function ctest()
clear;

n = 100;
k = 50;

t = linspace(0, pi/2, n);
a = 0.5; 
r = 2;
psi1 = r * cos(t); 
phi1 = a * r * sin(t); 

a = 2; 
r = 0.5;
psi2 = -r * cos(t(end:-1:1)); 
phi2 = a * r * sin(t(end:-1:1)); 

z = [psi1, psi2];
r = [phi1, phi2];

plot(z, r); figure(gcf); 
figure(2);
u = linspace(0, 2*pi, 50); 

[U,V] = ndgrid(u, 1:(2*n));
X = sin(U) .* r(V);
Y = cos(U) .* r(V); 
Z = z(V); 

colormap summer
surf(X, Y, -Z, 'LineStyle', 'none', 'FaceLighting', 'gouraud', 'BackFaceLighting', 'lit'); figure(gcf);
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 1]);
camlight
view -56 26
```

Comment: Professor Hughes  My  sincere  and  serious  thanks  for this  very  great  answer, a  concrete  example.

Comment: My pleasure; it was kinda fun searching around for it. I was expecting the end result to involve multiple pieces rather than just two -- blind luck!