# Is there significance to the maximum curvature of a Cartesian function?

Tags: reference-request, proof-explanation, curvature

The curvature $\kappa$ has been derived for functions in Cartesian coordinates as $$\kappa=\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{ \frac{3}{2}}}.$$ I noticed that the maximum value of the curvature typically corresponds a sort of$\dots$"vertex" looking point of a function where the tightness peaks as with $x=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\big(\dfrac{1}{2}\big)$ of $y=e^x,$ and I am wondering if there is information on that concerning a formal name for this point of maximum curvature or if there are any special properties of this point.

Comment: its y' at the denominator John

Comment: Oh yeah, I couldn't quite see it in wiki with the ' so close to the 2. Luckily it doesn't matter much for the case of $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes called a "vertex", and with that naming, probably the most famous use is in the four vertex theorem. See [wikipedia's article on the subject.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vertex_theorem)

Of possible related interest: 
[A generalization of the "Four vertex theorem"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072668/a-generalization-of-the-four-vertex-theorem/2110662#2110662)